# How to encrypt/decrypt synchronously using Web Crypto API?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes-gcm

**Basic Issue**: In order to catchup with latest security trend, I need to update to AES-GCM from AES-CBC. Currently, I am using "crypto-js" library for encryption and decryption in my Angular application.

**Web Crypto API**: I found that Web Crypto API for performing AES-GCM encryption/decryption and the simple HTML, JS POC is working fine as for my requirement.

**Problem with Web Crypto API in Angular App**: Web Crypto API is promise based and introducing new promise based API into an existing, stable application requires lot of code changes which I am afraid of because this entire shift of approach in Angular app might affect the stability of the Live application and might introduce new critical issues.

So, I request anyone please suggest any of the below,

1. Any Crypto library which is capable of doing AES-GCM synchronously
2. Any way to make the Web Crypto API as synchronous which requires minimal code changes

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a slam dunk solution for what you are looking for, however here are a few ideas.

1. There a few libraries that support AES-GCM and are synchronous:

   - The [aes-256-gcm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aes-256-gcm) package is one, although you would want to research it's security.
   - If you are using something like WebPack, you can also use the built in [Node Crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) library which can be polyfilled / packed into the browser.  See this [example](https://gist.github.com/rjz/15baffeab434b8125ca4d783f4116d81).  This is a little more complex, but more well-tested / evaluated from a security stand point.  I have recently used this approach in VueJS app and it worked just fine.
2. Unfortunately no, there is no way to make the WebCrypto API synchronous. There is no concept of waiting / blocking the execution event loop waiting for another task to completely within JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely consider using the Web Crypto API, it performs much better than any JS library and is safer to use.

The synchronous effect you could simply obtain using async/await

```
const encryptedData = await crypto.subtle.encrypt(
    algorithm,
    key,
    data
)
```